# Applying "not" operator on long double in C

Tags: c, sizeof, integer-promotion, long-double, not-operator

I have below C code in which I have applied a not operator on a long double variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   long double a;
   signed char b;
   int arr[sizeof(!a+b)];
   printf("\n%d",sizeof(arr));
   return 0;
}
```

This code outputs 16. I have problem in understanding what happenes when we apply not operator on long double, as we have done with `a`.

Please help me to understand whats happeneing with this code.

Thank You!

Comment: Why do you write code like that?

Comment: What output do you get if you don't negate?

Comment: `!a` has type `int`; `(!a) + b` has type `int` ... OTOH, depending on precedence (which I'm not even going to think about), `!(a + b)` has type `int` ==> the end result is the same: `sizeof (!a+b) == sizeof ((!a)+b) == sizeof (!(a+b)) == sizeof (int)`, so you have `int arr[4]`

Comment: What is wrong with this code? Have I written something wrong?

Comment: "when we apply not operator on long double" we get either `0` or `1` of type `int`

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI "Wrong" is subjective, but if you were trying to use a screwdriver to cut tomatoes, we would also ask why. So what are you trying to achieve with `sizeof(!a+b)`? It makes no sense.

Comment: I want to know what will be the exact value and datatype of !a and !b( had we done that)?

Comment: @klutt it was a question that came in my placement test. I haven't written that.

Comment: @pmg is it true with every datatype( i.e. char, float, int, double, long etc.)?

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI Ok. Well, the code makes no sense at all. It's only to see if you understand `sizeof` and implicit casts and promotions.

Comment: Yes @VIPULTYAGI, `!<anything>` has a value of `0` or `1` of type `int`

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI One interesting thing is that `sizeof i++` will NOT increment `i`.

Comment: Why is it so? Coz it is post increment??

Comment: @klutt Except when it will! `int i=1; int(*skunk)[i]; printf("%d\n",(sizeof(skunk[i++]),i));`  :)

Comment: "Coz it is post increment?" No, because `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand (except for VLA) ... `sizeof (1/sin(0))` does not divide by zero.

Comment: @Lundin Nice one!

Answer (score 8):

From the C Standard (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
> its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
> compares equal to 0. **The result has type int**. The expression !E is
> equivalent to (0==E).

So in this expression

```
sizeof(!a+b)
```

the sub-expression `!a` has the type `int`.

There are used the integer promotions of the operand `b` to the type `int` in the expression`!a + b` because the rank of the type `signed char` is less than the rank of the type `int` and the type `int` can represent all values of the type `signed char`.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> 2. ...If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>    by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>    otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>    integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
>    promotions.

So the full expression is equivalent to

```
sizeof( int )
```

If the `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then you have an array declared like

```
int arr[4];
```

Its size is equal to `16` that is to `4 * sizeof( int )`.